# Python remove data from a list to add into a new list

Tags: python, list, cpu-word, addition

Question: how to I remove the first word from a list to add into a new list called `car_list` and keep the rest to add into another list `other_list`.

In `other_list` I'm putting the rest into a dictionary

Such as when I read the file I get something like

`data_file = ['1911 Overland OctoAuto', '1913 Scripps-Booth Bi-Autogo','1920 Briggs and Stratton Flyer'`

`car_list = []`
`other_list = []`

***How do I get the outcome as followed***

```
car_list = [Overland, Scripps-Booth, Briggs]

other_list = [1911,OctoAuto, 1913, Bi-Autogo, 1920, and Stratton flyer]
```

***Here is what I have***

```
data_file = open("facts.txt", 'r')


def clean_list(data_file):
    new_list =[]
    clean_list =[]
    car_list = []
    other_list = []
    D = {}
    for i in data_file:
        new_list = data_file.split('\n') #change split by new line or word

    clean_list = [(x.strip(' ')) for x in new_list]
    car_list = (clean_list.strip().split(' ')[2:], ' ') 
    other_list = dict(zip(keys, values))# Just an example
    return car_list

car_list = clean_list(data_file)
```

I thought `car_list = (clean_list.strip().split(' ')[2:], ' ')`

would work but I get the following error.

```
car_list = (clean_list.lstrip().split(' ')[2:], ' ')
```

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lstrip'`

I thought by splicing would work but no dice.`

I tried `car_list = clean_list.split(' ',2)[2]` and prints nothing

any ideas? I know the file is being read for sure but I just dont know what to do here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My warning to you is that `other_list` looks like a mixture of different types of data. That's usually not wise. With that disclaimer, here's an attempt:

```
data_file = ['1911 Overland OctoAuto', 
             '1913 Scripps-Booth Bi-Autogo',
             '1920 Briggs and Stratton Flyer']

car_list = []
other_list = []
for entry in data_file:
    year, make, model = entry.split(' ',2)
    car_list.append(make)
    other_list.append(year)
    other_list.append(model)

print car_list
>>>> ['Overland', 'Scripps-Booth', 'Briggs']
print other_list
>>>> ['1911', 'OctoAuto', '1913', 'Bi-Autogo', '1920', 'and Stratton Flyer']
```

Answer (score 1):

Eventually you can use regex also to split the string.

```
import re
data_file = ['1911 Overland OctoAuto', 
             '1913 Scripps-Booth Bi-Autogo',
             '1920 Briggs and Stratton Flyer']

car_list = []
other_list = []
delimiter_space = re.compile(' ')
for entry in data_file:
    year, make, model = delimiter_space.split(entry,maxsplit=2)
    car_list.append(make)
    other_list.append(year)
    other_list.append(model)

print car_list
>>>> ['Overland', 'Scripps-Booth', 'Briggs']
print other_list
>>>> ['1911', 'OctoAuto', '1913', 'Bi-Autogo', '1920', 'and Stratton Flyer']
```

Comment: Much appreciated for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

```
T = [x.split(' ', 2) for x in data_file]
car_list = [ x[1] for x in T]
other_list =  [ v for x in T for v in x if v != x[1]]
print car_list
print other_list
```

**Output**

```
['Overland', 'Scripps-Booth', 'Briggs']
['1911', 'OctoAuto', '1913', 'Bi-Autogo', '1920', 'and Stratton Flyer']
```